# How can I loop through a HashMap table and send data from 1 row at a time with a button?

Tags: java, android

Noob programmer here! I want to loop through a HashMap and send the data from 1 row to a method with a button click. That is when i press the button once the data from the first row is sent into the method, when the button is pressed again the data from row nr 2 is sent into the method and so on.

How can I do that and is it even possible?

*EDIT* Code for the method:

```
    public void create_dialog_method(String question_param, final boolean identifier) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setMessage(question_param);

    alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

          if (identifier)

              showRiskEvaluationDialog();
          else 
              if (identifier == false);

              //<<<<<This is where i need a loop that only picks 1 row each time it's called>>>>
              for (Entry<String, Boolean> entry:  question_map.entrySet()){
                  create_dialog_method(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
              }


             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

          if (identifier)
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          else

          showRiskEvaluationDialog();
       }
    });
    alert.show();
 }
```

My class and onCreate(); including the Map with questions and "identifier" boolean value:

```
public class QuestionsActivity extends Activity {

Map<String, Boolean> question_map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean>();
int counter = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

    //false = call showRiskEvaluationDialog() on button NO
    //true  = call showRiskEvaluationDialog() on button YES


    question_map.put("8. Question8?", false);
    question_map.put("7. Question7?", false);
    question_map.put("6. Question6?", false);
    question_map.put("5. Question5?", false);
    question_map.put("4. Question4?", false);
    question_map.put("3. Question3?", false);
    question_map.put("2. Question2?", false);
    question_map.put("1. Question1?", false);

    create_dialog_method("asd2313", false);

    // For loop to extract a question and identifier from the Map
    /**
    for (Entry<String, Boolean> entry : question_map.entrySet()){
       create_dialog_method(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }//end for
    **/

}//end onCreate()
```

Comment: What is going on? It is third question about HashMap storing lists in last half of hour. Are you all from same class solving same homework?

Comment: @Pshemo Something like that yeah lol

Comment: Then you should (1) read [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) (2) after that if needed try to google it using query like "how to iterate over Map in Java" (3) after that if you still don't have good results try [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search) over Stack Overflow for similar questions (4) and lastly if there really are no good results ask question (but before you press button which will actually add your question to question lists check each of suggested related question).

Comment: @Pshemo yup done all that and unfortunally i didn't find anything that would help me solve my problem.

Comment: Rally? First two links from [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+i+iterate+over+map+in+java) seems to be nice results to me.

Comment: @Pshemo yeah I checked them out and tried them but they didn't solve my problem. Those loops iterate the whole map, which in my program call the method for every row in the Map. Resulting in 8 dialogs showing up with 1 button press. I want 1 dialog to show up with 1 button press.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the keySet() or entrySet() functions of the map. If you have a Map called myMap you can do something like this:

```
for(String key : myMap.keySet()){
String value = myMap.get(key);
writeDataSomewhere(key, value);

}
```

obviously the writeDataSomewhere() method is yours....not the Maps

Comment: Hmm It seems like it iterates over the whole map when i press the button so all the dialogs show up at once. I edited my post and pasted in my map and the method.

Comment: If you want only one entry and you know the key then don't do the loop just use the get() method. If you want to just get the first entry then put a break statement in the loop.

Comment: I want to dynamically send the next row of data into the method when the button is clicked. When i press the button first question in hashmap pops up in the dialog. When i press the button next time the data at the next row will be sent to the method and displayed in a dialog box, and so on. 

I'm not sure if my approach with hashmap is correct though.

Comment: oh... then you may need to hold the map at the class level and do a get() based on some counter everytime you click...

Comment: Ah okay! Can i keep everything in the same class?